# Apache Guacamole + Windows Active Directory Error 49

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I've configured my guacamole testing instance to the point where, when I enter a username and password at the prompt, I see an ldap bind request at my domain controller.

[image]
obviously that is not my real password

It then responds with invalidCredentials (49) and AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e

[image]

I've read that error 49 means that the username may be correct but the password is incorrect. Well I get the same response even with a bogus username. I'm assuming this odd response is some sort of brute force prevention.

Here is my guacamole.properties:

```
# LDAP properties
ldap-hostname: domain.xyz
ldap-user-base-dn:  cn=Users, dc=domain, dc=xyz
ldap-username-attribute: sAMAccountName
```

I'm running Guacamole 1.4 and Windows Server 2022

I have other services authenticating over LDAP already, like vSphere.

Comment: What other tools have you used to test that account with the LDAP bind? LDP?

Comment: @GregAskew I get a similar AcceptSecurityContext error and a Error 0x80090308 The token supplied to the function is invalid

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that this error message is regarding your LDAP bind dn (user).
Have you configured these properties with an active account from your domain:

```
ldap-search-bind-dn:
ldap-search-bind-password:
```

In case of active directory this can be any user, it just needs to be member of the domain.